# Looking for suggestion, loop terminate on time conditions

Tags: labview

I am trying to implement a simple python based code into the LabVIEW and for this, I am trying to implement this logic by using loop-timer termination but don't know how to run a loop that will terminate on time conditions.

Looking for your suggestions.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: question edited- thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by using local variables and while loop combinations [image].

Comment: This loop is not terminated on a time condition (and it doesn't use a local variable). If this is the answer to your question, please try to explain your question better!